# Issues in implementing ngx-owl-carousel-o inside the mat-accordion

Tags: typescript, angular7

Currently I am working on angular 7 & I am advisable to use only TS instead of JS. Hence I am using ngx-owl-carousel-o plugin for sliding the div/img. It is working  fine if I placed it outside of the mat-expansion-panel".  [image]

But if I am placing the same slider inside the "mat-expansion-panel" some width issue occured like below. [image]

I have found the issue too. But I don't know how to resolve it. Owl-carousel is taking the width of 6000px if it is placed outside the expansion panel. If I am placed inside inside the expansion panel it's only taking 80px width.

By default the plugin has "width" property too. Eventhough I have binded the width property same thing occured. below is my code.
**HTML:**

```
<mat-accordion>
       <mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="true">
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <mat-panel-title>
                Address Book
              </mat-panel-title>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
              <div class="card col-md-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="map-display" class="z-depth-1-half map-container">
                    <iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=chennai&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed"
                      frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
                  </div>
                  <div class="maxminIcon"><img src="../assets/images/Maximise.PNG" *ngIf="!opened" (click)="open()" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-9">
                <owl-carousel-o  [options]="customOptions2">
                  <ng-template carouselSlide>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 p-1">Primary Address</h6>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker paddingrl-20"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 col-11">
                            <span>Suresh Chakravarthy <br>
                              3/17, 14-757, First Street, Vijaya Colony, Sakthi Nagar,Guindy,Chennai, <br>
                              Kancheepuram, Tamilnadu, India, 600 006
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <mat-divider class="m-2"></mat-divider>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>044-1254638</span></div>
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-mobile  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>9876543210</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>Sureshkumar@gmail.com</span></div>
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-fax  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>2222-3333</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-compass paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 col-11">
                            <span class="col-md-5 p-0">380.000000<span>&nbsp;</span>
                              407.0999999</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ng-template>
                  <ng-template  carouselSlide>
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 p-1">Postal Address 1</h6>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker paddingrl-20"></i>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 col-11">
                            <span>Suresh Chakravarthy <br>
                              3/17, 14-757, First Street, Vijaya Colony, Sakthi Nagar,Guindy,Chennai, <br>
                              Kancheepuram, Tamilnadu, India, 600 006
                            </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <mat-divider class="m-2"></mat-divider>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>044-1254638</span></div>
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-mobile  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>9876543210</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>Sureshkumar@gmail.com</span></div>
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-fax  paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-5">
                            <span>2222-3333</span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-xl-1 col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-1 p-0">
                            <i class="fa fa-compass paddingrl-20 "></i> </div>
                          <div class="col-xl-11 col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 col-11">
                            <span class="col-md-5 p-0">380.000000<span>&nbsp;</span>
                              407.0999999</span></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </ng-template>
                 </owl-carousel-o>
              </div>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>
```

**CSS:**

```
.owl-carousel .owl-nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}

.owl-carousel .nav-btn {
  position: absolute;
   cursor: pointer;
  top: 44% !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1579ab;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
.owl-carousel .active{
  border: 1px solid #1579ab;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
} 

.owl-carousel .active ~ .active{
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
} 
.owl-carousel .owl-prev.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-next.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.owl-carousel .nav-btn:before{
  vertical-align: middle;

}
.owl-carousel .prev-slide {
  left: -25px;
}

.owl-carousel .next-slide {
  right: -25px;
}

.owl-carousel .prev-slide:hover {
  background-position: 0px -53px;
}

.owl-carousel .next-slide:hover {
  background-position: -24px -53px;
}
```

**TS:**

```
customOptions2 : any ={
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: false,
    dots: false,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText:  ["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide fa fa-angle-right'></div>", "<div class='nav-btn next-slide fa fa-angle-left'></div>"],
    isActive: true,
    margin: 10,
    responsiveRefreshRate: 5000,
    autoWidth: true,
    width: 1000,
    carouselWindowWidth: 6000,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      400: {
        items: 2
      }
      },
    nav: true
  }
```

Kindly help me to resolve this width issue.